# To prevent BadUSB attacks - can't you just block a connection to the specific vulnerable microcontrollers?

Tags: access-control, usb, badusb

Since only a select amount of amount of microcontrollers in the USBs can be reprogrammed, isn't it just possible to block that certain kinds of microcontroller containing devices?

Comment: Sure. How do you do that? Do you have a means to inspect the USB and then control whether it has access? How can you be sure that a re-written firmware will report itself accurately?

Comment: I am by no means an expert in this field, but maybe you can somehow get the hardware information somehow in a sandbox or something?..

Comment: So, "can't you just" is not a helpful place to start when you don't know if the capability exists; "can't you just hover in midair?" There are ways to control USB, and you are limited by their capabilities. First confirm whether this control exists, then consider whether it is possible to know enough firmware models to make this control useful, and then, whether a compromised firware would report itself accurately to know whether the control is viable.

Comment: So, the answer to the question you asked is "yes". But the "how" is the much bigger concern. "Can't you just hover in midair to prevent tripping?" "Yes. But how are you going to hover?"

Comment: While it seems at first blush to be reasonable, what you are suggesting is a variant of *IEEE RFC 3514* put out on **April 1** , 2003. Also known as the **Evil Bit** , https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3514.

Comment: I see, I doubt it's possible to edit the question to make it realistically answerable...